# Double-Signing .apk // SHA1 & other issues

Tags: java, android, algorithm, apk, jarsigner

I am currently facing some problems with double-signing an .apk.
The normal workflow was always:

```
zip -d FILE.apk META-INF/\*
jarsigner -verbose -keystore EXTERNAL.keystore FILE.apk EXTERNAL
jarsigner -verbose -keystore INTERNAL FILE.apk INTERNAL
zipalign -v 4 FILE.apk FILE_ALIGNED.apk
```

**When using this original method, I am receiving an error from the Google Play Store:**

*You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer INTERNAL.RSA): JAR signature META-INF/INTERNAL.RSA uses digest algorithm 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 and signature algorithm 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 which is not supported on API Levels [[14, 17]]*

**Since I am getting this algorithm error only for the "INTERNAL.RSA" I tried using:**

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore INTERNAL FILE.apk INTERNAL
```

**This results in another error:**

*You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer EXTERNAL.DSA): No digest for assets/www/assets/fonts/FONT.ttf in META-INF/EXTERNAL.SF*

This is just a small snippet of the error, because it lists every asset of the app with the same error. I am thankful for every help or hint about how to resolve this issue.

Cheers,
Marius

Comment: Regarding the second error: (1) Did you add -sigalg and -digestalg params into your original four lines of script and retry, or did you run the modified jarsigner command after the previous two on the same file? (2) Are there any other errors or warnings from Play other than "No digest for ... in META-INF/EXTERNAL.SF"

Comment: I retried to sign with the -sigalg and -digestalg on a new file. I am always using a copy of the original file to sign it and if it doesn't work I am deleting it. Sadly, there are no other erros shown, other than "No digest for...Asset XY".

Comment: Please add the contents of the `assets/www/assets/fonts/FONT.ttf` section of `META-INF/EXTERNAL.SF` from the APK about which Play (or `apksigner verify`) is complaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try switching from `jarsigner` to `apksigner` (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html). The original four commands switch to:

```
zipalign -v -p 4 FILE.apk FILE_ALIGNED.apk
apksigner sign --ks EXTERNAL.keystore --next-signer --ks INTERNAL FILE_ALIGNED.apk
```

The first error in OP is due to RSA with SHA-256 APK signatures (default in modern `jarsigner`) not being supported on platforms older than API Level 18 (Jelly Bean MR2) and the APK's AndroidManifest.xml declaring (via `android:minSdkVersion`) that the APK supports running on platforms with API Level 14 and higher.

P. S. You can approximate Play's APK signature checking behavior by running

```
apksigner verify some.apk
```

Comment: I will try to use apksigner and will comment later today, as soon as I have a result. Thanks for your help so far!